# Modular arithmetic, Discrete math.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Let $m$ be a prime number and $r \in \mathbb{N}$.

We'll define $x = (x_1,...,x_r) \; y = (y_1,...,y_r)\;$ such that $x_i \neq y_i \; \forall\; 1 \leq i \leq r$.

Also, let $(a_1,...a_r)$ be a sequence of numbers such that $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, specifically $ 0 \leq a_i \leq m-1 \; \forall\; 1 \leq i \leq r $.

How many sequences $(a_1,...a_r)$ exist such that  $(\sum_{i=1}^{r}a_ix_i)  \bmod m = (\sum_{j=1}^{r}a_jy_j)\bmod  m$ ?

I understand the concept of the question, I wrote the above equation as $(\sum_{i=1}^{r}a_i(x_i-y_i))\bmod   m = 0$.

Obviously $(x_i-y_i)$ can be anything but $0$, however  $(x_i-y_i) \bmod  m $ can be $0$.

How do I solve this question? is this a question in combinatorics maybe?

Comment: Try it for $r=1$, $r=2$, etc. and see if you can find a pattern.

Comment: @saulspatz for $r=1$ there's obviously 1 option, however I didn't manage to find a pattern..

Comment: That's not right.  If $x_1\equiv y_1\pmod{m}$ then there are $m$ solutions.

Comment: @saulspatz That's right. My mistake on that end. How do you expand it though? mind elaborating?

Comment: I haven't done it, but I think you have to break it into two cases as above.  If $x_r\neq y_r\pmod{m}$ then whatever values are assigned to $a_1,\dots, a_{r-1}$ there is exactly one possibility for $a_r$, so the answer is $m^{r-1}$  Then you have to deal with the case $x_r\equiv y_r\pmod{m}$  All values of $a_r$ give $0$, so there are $m$ times the number of solutions for $(x_1,\dots,x_{r-1}), (y_1,\dots,y_{r-1})$  Now you should be able to do it for small $r$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

If for every $1\leq i\leq r$ we have $x_i\equiv y_i \pmod{}m$, then any values of $a_i,\ i=1,\dots,r$ give a solutions, so there are $m^r$ solutions in that case.

If not, then we may assume without loss of generality that $X_1\neq y_1\pmod{m}$.  We can assign whatever values we like to $a_2,\dots, a_r$ and then we must take $$a_1= -(x_1-y_1)^{-1}\sum_{i=2}^r a_i(x_i-y_i),$$ where all computations (in particular the multiplicative inverse) are performed modulo $m$.  Thus in this case, there are $m^{r-1}$ solutions.